# Networkx edge attribute

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed graph like this-

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('a', 'b', attr=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', attr=0.2)
G.add_edge('d', 'a', attr=0.3)
```

How can I iter over node 'a' to get the attributes in following format

```
[0.6, 0.2, -0.3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is one solution by iterating through the `edges.data()` of the Graph. P.S: I basically used tab completions in JuPyter to find the attributes and then came up with the following solution by playing around with different attributes. This code will only give you the attributes for `'a'` as you asked for. So if you add a fourth node as `G.add_edge('d', 'b', attr=0.7)`, the output will be `[0.6, 0.2, -0.3]` where the fourth node is not counted.

```
attributes = []

for edge in G.edges.data():
    if edge[0] == 'a':
        attributes.append(edge[-1]['attr'])
    elif edge[1] == 'a'   :
        attributes.append(-edge[-1]['attr'])

print (attributes)    
# [0.6, 0.2, -0.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, though there are likely better ways:

```
In [3]: [G[e[0]][e[1]]['attr'] for e in  G.out_edges('a')] + [-G[e[0]][e[1]]['attr'] for e in  G.in_edges('a')]

Out[3]: [0.6, 0.2, -0.3]
```

The code above uses two list comprehensions to loop though all the outbound and inbound edges from `a` and picks the attribute from the edges, assigning a negative value if it's from an inbound edge.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all the edges would be costly, when we have large graphs. 
I would recommend the finding the successors and predecessors of a particular node and then get the information about the corresponding edge.

```
[G.get_edge_data('a',neigh)['attr'] for neigh in G.successors('a')] + \
[-G.get_edge_data(neigh,'a')['attr'] for neigh in G.predecessors('a')]
```